# Oracle E business suite update_cust_acct_site

Tags: oracle-apps

Created an account site for an account through in oracle e-Business Suite screen.
Wrote a service to update this account site from other third party application. So calling API **update_cust_acct_site** from C# to update the account site details. It called the API and updated the detail well in ebs table. I can query it in oracle table through sql developer. But I could not see the account, account site in oracle e-Business Suite application screen.

In this way, I am also updating Location, party site and customer sit use objects using the API.

Why i could not see it in e-Business Suite after calling the API?

Should I need to run anything else to make it visible in application?

please help me.
I am not good in Oracle / EBS stuffs.

thanks

Comment: Check the form code, which you are using for querying the Customer Account. The form will be using a view, maybe that view has a join which is failing in your case

Comment: Found a solution. It is related to User Responsibility. After initialized correct responsibility, it is started to show in EBS screen.

Comment: how did you write the api service? what libs/connectors have you used? actually I'm stuck in a situation where I have some data I need to update in EBS financial module using a third party application, and I'm a lil bit lost, any links/help would be appreciated

Comment: I used TCA APIs. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13662/T358453T358465.htm Instead of Java used C# to call these APIs programmatically.